# Spectral sequence associated to the stupid filtration

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

In *Methods of Homological Algebra* by Gelfand and Manin, they define the spectral sequence associated to a filtered complex $(K^{\bullet},d^{\bullet})$. For example, the stupid filtration is defined as follows:

$$(F^pK^{\bullet})^n = \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if }\ n<p \\
      K^n & \text{if }\ n \geq p
    \end{cases}$$

Define $$Z^{p,q}_r := d^{-1}(F^{p+r}K^{p+q+1}) \cap F^p K^{p+q} \subset K^{p+q}$$

G&M assert that

$$Z_r^{p,q} = \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if }\ q < 0 \\
      \text{ker}(d^{p+q}) & \text{if }\ q \geq 0, r<q+1 \\
      K^{p+q} & \text{if } q \geq 0, r \geq q+1
    \end{cases}$$

However, this seems wrong to me. We have

$$F^{p+r}K^{p+q+1} = \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if }\ r>q+1 \\
      K^{p+q} & \text{if } r \leq q+1
    \end{cases}$$

So $d^{-1}(F^{p+r}K^{p+q+1})$ should be all of $K^{p+q}$ for $r$ small compared to $q$, not the other way around. Likewise, $d^{-1}(F^{p+r}K^{p+q+1})$ should be the kernel of $d$ for $r$ large compared to $q$, and not the other way around.

Am I making a mistake?